# Vue vuex shorten mapState

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store, vuex-modules

Thats how my code looksin my vue component and as you can see there is a module inputValues, and the last three path to state are almost the same.

Is there possiility to make it shorter? becouse it gonnabe similiar and more in other components.

```
 export default {
      components: {
        actionBar,
        dialogTutorials
      },
      name: 'Spells',
      computed: {
          ...mapState({
              dialogOpen: state => state.inputValues.lofGlobals.dialogOpen,
              stage1heal: state => state.inputValues.lof.spellsTab.stage1heal,
              stage2heal: state => state.inputValues.lof.spellsTab.stage2heal,
              Sio: state => state.inputValues.lof.spellsTab.Sio,
              cast: state => state.inputValues.lof.spellsTab.cast,
          }),
        },
```

Comment: I would re-define those as getters in your Vuex module, and then use `mapGetter` in your components.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think it can't be shorter.
If your multiple components use `state.inputValues`, you can use [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components.